# celery task raise an error while redis backend connection socket timeout

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, redis, celery

I am using celery to run task one by one with redis broker, but when i run 2 task then after completing the first redis given an timeout socket error for second task so that second task would be failed.

```
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/aide_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 194, in get
on_message=on_message,
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/aide_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/async.py", line 189, in wait_for_pending
for _ in self._wait_for_pending(result, **kwargs):
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/aide_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/async.py", line 256, in _wait_for_pending
on_interval=on_interval):
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/aide_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/async.py", line 57, in drain_events_until
yield self.wait_for(p, wait, timeout=1)
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/aide_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/async.py", line 66, in wait_for
wait(timeout=timeout)
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/aide_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 69, in drain_events
m = self._pubsub.get_message(timeout=timeout)
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/aide_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 2513, in get_message
response = self.parse_response(block=False, timeout=timeout)
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/aide_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 2430, in parse_response
return self._execute(connection, connection.read_response)
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/aide_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 2408, in _execute
return command(*args)
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/aide_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 624, in read_response
response = self._parser.read_response()
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/aide_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 284, in read_response
response = self._buffer.readline()
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/aide_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 216, in readline
self._read_from_socket()
File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/aide_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 187, in _read_from_socket
raise TimeoutError("Timeout reading from socket")
TimeoutError: Timeout reading from socket
```

I am running celery by using this command:

```
celery -A flask_application.celery worker --loglevel=info --max-tasks-per-child=1 --concurrency=1
```

I am calling celery task by using: `.delay()` function

```
celery_response = run_algo.run_pipeline.delay(request.get_json())
```

Getting output by using: `.get()` function

```
output_file_path = celery_response.get()
```

Comment: can you provide a simple task that will always fail?

Answer (score 0):

There's a warning in the docs of [AsyncResult.get](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.AsyncResult.get) saying that calling it it within an async task can cause a deadlock, which may be what's happening here, though it's hard to tell without more context of where these things are being called.